# Call an entity method in a controller

Tags: symfony

i have three entities: Invoice,Payment and Result

the relationships between entities are: 
Result(1,1)-------------(1,n)Invoice(1,n)---------------(1,1)Payment 
here's my problem :I would like in my PaymentController when I create a new payement ,I retrieve Invoice entity and in the same PaymentController I create  a new Result.

here's my PaymentController code:

```
use MyApp\AccountBundle\Entity\Result;
class PaymentController  extends Controller
  public function createAction()
    {
     $entity  = new Payment();
     $request = $this->getRequest();
     $form    = $this->createForm(new PaymentType(), $entity);
     $form->bindRequest($request);
     $amount=$form->get('amountreceived')->getData();
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $invoice = em->getRepository('MyAppAccountBundle:Invoice')->find($entity->getInvoice()->getId())
        if (!$invoice) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Invoice entity.');
            } 
             $result=new Result();
             $result=setDebitAmount($amount);
     $result=setCreditAmount(0);
     $result=setInvoice($invoice);
             $em->persist($result);
             $em->persist($entity);
             $em->flush();
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payment_show', array('id' =>   $entity->getId())));   
    }
    return $this->render('MyAppAccountBundle:Payment:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    ));
```

when a execute PaymentController (in view) i get error:
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function MyApp\AccountBundle\Controller\setDebitAmount() in C:\wamp\www\account\src\ MyApp\AccountBundle\Controller\PaymentController.php on line...

thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `=` to `->`

```
$result=setDebitAmount($amount);
```

must be

```
$result->setDebitAmount($amount);
```